# Add extra data in ajax:beforeSend (link_to)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to, link-to-remote

I have a `link_to` with `remote:` set to true. What I want to do is add an extra attribute with the request so I tried it with this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(
      function(){
        $("#part_btn").bind("ajax:beforeSend",
            function(event, xhr, settings, data){
              settings.data += "&user_id=5"
            })
      })
</script>
```

Now I don't even know if this is possible because the `user_id` is never sent to the controller and when I log the `setting.data` I get `null&user_id=5`.

If it's not possible like this, is there any other way to do it?

EDIT:

I didn't add an extra parameter to the `link_to` because the user_id actually comes from a select tag and I wanted to add the selected value as extra data like this:

```
settings.data += ("&user_id="+$("#register_user_id option:selected").val());
```

this is what my `link_to` looks like:

```
  <%= text_field_tag :part_id, nil, :class => 'text_field', data: {source: autocomplete_parts_for_registers_registers_path} %>
  <%= link_to('toevoegen', '#!', id: 'part_btn', class: 'btn btn-small btn-success addbtn', style: "margin-top: 5px", data: {source: add_part_registers_path}, remote: true) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking the javascript approach, consider send the params with the route in the `link_to`:

```
link_to "My link", some_path(user_id: 5), remote: true, method: :post
```

This will add `:user_id` with a value of 5 to the params in the controller for `some_path`.

Additionally, you can use the `data:` attribute on the link to to add any params you want to XHR request.

```
link_to "My link", id: "user_link", some_path, remote: true, method: :post, data: { params: { user_id: 123 }.to_param }
```

If you need to change the value dynamically:

```
$("#user_select").change(function() {
  user_id = $(this).val();
  $("#user_link").data("params", "user_id=" + user_id);
})
```

[In fact, it looks like this is exactly what Rails does to send AJAX values from jquery_ujs.](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L136)

Obviously, be sure to check the value of `user_id` server-side.

Comment: I thought of this as well but I want to send a value selected from a select tag, I just simplified my code so it's easier to read (maybe not a good idea).

Comment: Ok, then you can dynamically change the value of the `data-params="user_id=5"` using the `$('#user_select').change` event.

Comment: Ok I'll try this one first, but is there no way to add data within the ajax:beforeSend?

Comment: I don't think think there's a simple way. Even Rails itself doesn't modify `ajax:beforeSend` to send params, it uses the approach above, which in my opinion is the cleaner approach since you can debug from Rails console more easily. I'm not sure if `settings` is read-only. If this is a `GET` request, you may be able to append to the URL with `settings.url +=  &newProp=newValue`. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: the `$("#user_link").data("params") = "user_id=" + user_id;` gives me "must be lvalue" error, is that the right way to edit it?

Comment: Mistake my part, it should be `$("#user_link").data("params", "user_id=" + user_id);` (Can't assign a value to the return value of a function).

Comment: Ok the data params changed but the user_id isn't send to the server... I added my `link_to` in my question in case there is something wrong with it

Comment: Can you include what the code for the #user_link HTML tag looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111103/discussion-between-anthony-e-and-kupi).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and easiest way to update link_to when user change drop-down by javascript or an extra ajax call

```
JS
$("#user_select").change(function() {
  user_id = $(this).val();
  $("#user_link").data("params") = "user_id=" + user_id;
})

Extra Ajax
send user_id to server with user_id and make a method_name.js.erb and update link from there
like:
link_to "link", method_path(user_id: params[:user_id]), remote: true
```